# How to change amount decimal digit numbers based on another field record

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

How to change quantity field decimal number based on field decimal_digit record

```py
class AccountAnalyticInvoiceLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.analytic.invoice.line'
    quantity = fields.Float(digits=(16, 2)
```

```py
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'
    
    decimal_digit = fields.Integer(string='Decimal Digit', default=2)
```

I tried tried

```py
@api.onchange('decimal_digits')
    def _onchange_decimal_digits(self):
        for record in self:
            record.quantity = round(record.quantity, record.decimal_digits)
```

but it seems not working

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the following two topics? Firstly why do you want to do that? And secondly why isn't it enough using Odoo's currency system? Little hint: don't use python default round mechanism but instead Odoo's tools (look into odoo.tools.float_utils).

Comment: @CZoellner I need to make custom configuration that quantity field is float type as default with 2 digit decimal numbers on behind and its decimal digits can be adjusted based decimal_digit field value. I mean, if decimal_digit value changed to 3 then quantity field decimal digit numbers become 3

Comment: Sounds very complicated and is difficult to solve in Odoo, because Odoo is built around let's call them "stable decimal numbers". The big difficulty here will be the client, because IIRC changing decimal numbers will force a user to reload the page, to see the change. Simple python code won't be enough here.